# how to display toast using Notification service using gcm intent in android

Tags: android

```
package com.lociiapp;

import android.app.Application;

public class LociiApplication extends Application{

    public static boolean isActivityVisible() {
        return activityVisible;
      }  

      public static void activityResumed() {
        activityVisible = true;
      }

      public static void activityPaused() {
        activityVisible = false;
      }

      private static boolean activityVisible;
      public static String FID = "";

}
```

This is my Application class code there GCM intent service :

```
public class GcmIntentService extends IntentService {


}
```

here i want when App is open then There should be no toast Message should display when app is close then Notification toast should visible  please tell me me how to hide notification in when activity is foreground and  show notification when app is close or paused. please help me how i will Implement this android.

Comment: @KDeogharkar hi u there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try following code in `onResume()` method of your application class.

```
public class CustomApplication extends Application 
{

    private static Context mContext;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        mContext = getApplicationContext();
    }

    public static void activityResumed() {
        // your code

        //call method to discard notification. 
        cancelNotification(mContext,0);
    } 

    public static void cancelNotification(Context context, int notifyId) {
        String ns = Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE;
        NotificationManager nMgr = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(ns);
        nMgr.cancel(notifyId);
    }
}
```

**Note**

You need to store your previous notification ids which you have shown in GCMIntent service. Either in preference or in file. You need to get that notification id while discarding notification.

Comment: APP_CONTEXT how to get this value

Answer (score 0):

Override `onResume()` and `onPause()` methods inside `LociiApplication` activity:

```
protected void onPause(){
    // show your notification here
    super.onPause();
}

@Override
protected void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    // hide your notification here
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy(){
    // do something when activity is destroyed
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

Learn more about [Notification](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html).

Comment: NotificationManager nMgr = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
  nMgr.cancelAll();
       This i have Put in onresumed method but when app is open then also Notifcation show its not ivisible

Comment: Try to set ID for your notification. To show the notification back, update it using its ID, instead of create a new notification.

Comment: http://paste.ofcode.org/33nzKjnQKtmgkAtsE5CHrMy this code i have applied but not working @ Albert Nicko